# convergent series notation

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm reading a book with the following definition of convergent series. I was hoping somebody could help me understand the notation.

A sequence of points $\left \{ x^k \right \}$ in $R^n$ is said to $\textit{converge}$ to a limit $x$ if the distance $d(x_k,x)$ between $x_k$ and $x$ tends to zero a $k$ goes to infinity, i.e., if for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists an integer $k(\epsilon)$ such that for all $k \geq k(\epsilon)$, we have  $d(x_k,x) < \epsilon$.

Now intuitively this is very clear. What I do not get is the notation. $\epsilon$ is any real positive number but what is $k(\epsilon)$? In this notation it appears as if $k$ a function of $\epsilon$. Basically what is the difference between $\epsilon$ and $k(\epsilon)$?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the definition says that

> for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists an integer $k(\epsilon)$

which means that given some $\epsilon > 0$, we can give a corresponding $k(\epsilon)$ so that the inequality is satisfied. However, we will in general not be able to find a $k(\epsilon)$ that works for *all* $\epsilon > 0$, so you can think of $k(\epsilon)$ as a function of $\epsilon$ (alternatively, you could write $k_\epsilon$ and think of $k$ as depending on $\epsilon$) that gives you an integer that works for this $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Great thanks a lot - very clear now.